# Executing cascading triggers returns error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted"

Tags: t-sql, triggers, cascading-deletes

I cannot seem to get my triggers to work as I expect, with me getting the error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression"

I have created several triggers that I use to achieve a cascading delete effect. I am using EF although I can't use it's Cascading Delete fuctionality as there are multiple delete paths in my database.

Anyway every time I delete a company and thus execute the DeleteCompany trigger, I get the above error. I have tried taking out some trigger which I believed to be the cause of the error but I get it every time.

Here are my triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteCompany 
    ON [dbo].[CompanySet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[EmployeeSet]
    WHERE CompanyId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[TemplateSet]
    WHERE CompanyId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[SettingSet]
    WHERE CompanyId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted) AND EmployeeId = NULL

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[CustomerSet]
    WHERE CompanyId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteEmployee 
    ON [dbo].[EmployeeSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[SettingSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[FavoriteSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ProjectEmployeeSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActivityBaseSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActivityReportSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteRole
    ON [dbo].[RoleSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[AccountRoleSet]
    WHERE RolesId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)    
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteCustomer
    ON [dbo].[CustomerSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ProjectSet]
    WHERE CustomerId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted) 
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteProject
    ON [dbo].[ProjectSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[TemplateSet]
    WHERE ProjectId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActivityBaseSet_Activity]
    WHERE ProjectId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActivityReportSet]
    WHERE ProjectId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[FavoriteSet]
    WHERE ProjectId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ProjectEmployeeSet]
    WHERE ProjectId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteSettingDefinition
    ON [dbo].[SettingDefinitionSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[SettingSet]
    WHERE SettingDefinitionId = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)    
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteTemplate
    ON [dbo].[TemplateSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[ActivityReportSet] SET [dbo].[ActivityReportSet].TemplateId = NULL
    FROM deleted
    WHERE [dbo].[ActivityReportSet].TemplateId = deleted.Id
GO
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace all your "=" with "IN" operator for your sub queries like:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[EmployeeSet]
    WHERE CompanyId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)
```

Comment: Although I still have some undeleted entities for some reason in my EmployeeSet and CustomerSet tables, this seems to do the trick, provided that the second problem doesn't lie with the usage of the IN keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the below Query

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteCompany 
    ON [dbo].[CompanySet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[EmployeeSet]
    WHERE CompanyId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[TemplateSet]
    WHERE CompanyId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[SettingSet]
    WHERE CompanyId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted) AND EmployeeId IS NULL

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[CustomerSet]
    WHERE CompanyId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteEmployee 
    ON [dbo].[EmployeeSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[SettingSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[FavoriteSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ProjectEmployeeSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActivityBaseSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActivityReportSet]
    WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteRole
    ON [dbo].[RoleSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[AccountRoleSet]
    WHERE RolesId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)    
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteCustomer
    ON [dbo].[CustomerSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ProjectSet]
    WHERE CustomerId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted) 
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteProject
    ON [dbo].[ProjectSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[TemplateSet]
    WHERE ProjectId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActivityBaseSet_Activity]
    WHERE ProjectId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActivityReportSet]
    WHERE ProjectId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[FavoriteSet]
    WHERE ProjectId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ProjectEmployeeSet]
    WHERE ProjectId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteSettingDefinition
    ON [dbo].[SettingDefinitionSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[SettingSet]
    WHERE SettingDefinitionId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)    
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteTemplate
    ON [dbo].[TemplateSet]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[ActivityReportSet] SET [dbo].[ActivityReportSet].TemplateId = NULL
    FROM deleted
    WHERE [dbo].[ActivityReportSet].TemplateId = deleted.Id
GO
```